# Why there is Server Connection "Online" While Developing WebParts in VS2012 for SP2013

Tags: development, web-part, 2013

I am new to SharePoint. And though I am taking my training on [CloudShare](http://www.cloudshare.com/) by creating cloud machine of **SharePoint-2013**.

When ever I am developing any visual WebPart in Visual Studio 2012 there is one property called `ServerConnection` of the Project Which is always set to `Online`.

I want know that why it is set to Online? When I use one WebPart which was developed in SharePoint 2010 in that there was not set that property to online. when I changed the Site URL property It automatically changed to Online.

And now I have installed SharePoint-2013 in my PC and VS2012 also. And in that again the same property is displaying. `ServerConnection : Online`.

Is it because I am using the [CloudShare](http://www.cloudshare.com/) Or there are different reasons for deploying the WebParts???

Thank you in advance for the answers...!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has to do something with you being on CloudShare. I get the same value of the property when I am completely on-premise on my local dev box.

This property was a new inclusion in Visual Studio 2012 tooling to show you whether Visual Studio can connect to the SharePoint Site which you have specified in the Site Url property.

> The SharePoint section includes the Active Deployment Configuration
>   property, which you use to specify the series of steps that are
>   performed during deployment; the Server Connection property, which you
>   use to specify whether the project connects to the server that's
>   running SharePoint; and the Site URL property, which you use to
>   specify the URL where the app for SharePoint is located.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220042.aspx#SP15projprop_properties

The link focuses on App Project properties but the same should hold true for Web Part Projects too.